# Cutting ropes such as to create two sets with equal number of blue and red stones

Tags: combinatorics

Given a rope with a Start and an End, and a number of Blue and Red stones that can slide in this rope such as to create a file of stones.

For a given sequence of blue and red stones, what’s the minimum number of cuts required to ensure that the resulting rope sections can be combined to form two separate sets with equal number of Blue and red stones?

Does the number of cuts depend on the sequence of colours?

What’s the number of cuts required for stones with n different colours?

Comment: "sets with equal number of blue and red stones" means $\textrm{Blue}(A) = \textrm{Red}(A)$ and $\textrm{Blue}(B) = \textrm{Red}(B)$, or $\textrm{Blue}(A) = \textrm{Blue}(B)$ and $\textrm{Red}(A) = \textrm{Red}(B)$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_splitting_problem

Comment: It means Blue(A)=Blue(B) and Red(A)=Red(B), i.e. same number of blue stones  e same number of red stones in the two sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume the number of blue stones, $b$, and red stones, $r$, are even.

Form a circle with the rope with the stones equally placed on this circle. Draw a diagonal in an arbitrary position and rotate this diameter. There may initially be more red stones on one side of the diameter than the other but this imbalance will be reversed when the diagonal has rotated $180^o$. So for some diagonal there are equal numbers of red stones on each side of the diameter and therefore also equal numbers of blue stones.

Cut the rope at the points indicated by the diameter and put together the  section(s) of rope containing the start and end points.

At most $2$ cuts are required. (It will be less than $2$ if the chosen diameter indicates the start and end point.)